# Is there a way to pipe the smoke test output outside the agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a release pipeline with a QA/Smoke Test stage, that generates XML files containing test results.

If I run this manually on my machine, obviously I have access to the XML files and I can see the details but on the agent I cannot since we don't have access to those Microsoft hosted agents to view the files.

Is there a way to pipe the files "out" in the task for viewing? maybe there's a third marketplace task that can achieve that?

Here's the deployment result:

```
2021-06-06T23:34:19.1260519Z Results File: D:\a\r1\a\qa-automation\TestResults\CurrentReport\Logs\junit.xml
2021-06-06T23:34:19.2448029Z Results File: D:\a\r1\a\qa-automation\TestResults\.\CurrentReport\Logs\detailedLogs.xml
2021-06-06T23:34:19.2533810Z 
2021-06-06T23:34:19.2596243Z Failed!  - Failed:    22, Passed:     2, Skipped:     0, Total:    24, Duration: 52 m 11 s - EED.dll (netcoreapp3.1)
```

Here's the stage YAML:

```
steps:
- script: |
   git clone https://.../qa-automation.git -b master
   
   cd qa-automation
   
   testrun.bat --cat "EDSmoke" --env dev
   
  displayName: 'Clone qa-automation repo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to pipe the files "out" in the task for viewing? maybe there's a 3rd marketplace task that can achieve that?

You can try with following task:

```
Write-host "##vso[task.uploadfile]<PathOfTheFiles>\<filename>"
```

Like:

```
Write-host "##vso[task.uploadfile]$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\qa-automation\TestResults\CurrentReport\Logs\junit.xml"
```

> View and download attachments associated with releases
>
> Would you like to upload additional logs or diagnostics or images when
> running tasks in a release? This feature enables users to upload
> additional files during deployments. To upload a new file, use the
> following agent command in your script:
>
> Write-host "##vso[task.uploadfile]"
>
> The file is then available as part of the release logs. When you
> download all the logs associated with the release, you will be able to
> retrieve this file as well.

You can also add a powershell script task in your release definition to read the smoke test output and output it to the console. Then you will be see the content of the log files from "**Logs**" tab powershell script step. And you can also click "**Download all logs as zip**" to download the smoke test result files.